# Is there a memory limit available for widgets?

Tags: java, android, memory, widget

I have a widget with ViewFlipper that flips between X number of images. I aim for 10 images to be flipped, and I can do this if I load very small images. My widget is size 4x2 and I want to display images with good quality, but I can't achieve this. Everything loads fine, no exceptions, but the widget never displays them. If I load very small image sizes (100x100 px), it starts flipping them. If I load larger image size (300x300), it won't start flipping the images until I reduce the number of images (flips) to 4.
This suggests a memory limitation to me, but I would expect an exception to be thrown somewhere after I do `appWidgetManager.updateWidget(widgetId, remoteViewFlipper)`.
Going through the logs, I don't see anything nearly related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on concrete implementation of launcher -  widget stuff is hosted  and processsed there. You updtes are send as parcelables, so there soule be data size limit as well:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/26ce74534024f41a?pli=1

Comment: Looks like you can `setDataSize()` on the parcelable, a bit unsafe, but it might do the trick. Thank you for the helpful info.